# element style has different value from computed style

Tags: css, computed-style

I came across a puzzling issue, where the computed style of an attribute has a different value than the element's style.

A few words first to describe my situation

I am animating the background-color property of an element and when the animation ends, 
I retrieve the computed bgcolor value and apply it to the element's style. This works fine

However, if I try now to alter the bgcolor nothing happens, although the value is indeed set on the element, as the developer tools report.

At this point if you toggle (through the browser's developer tools) between style and computed style, there is a discrepancy between what the 2 report, with the computed style taking precedence of course.

I have created a test script on fiddle that depicts the situation
http://jsfiddle.net/d2S3d/14/

Attaching also some sample css cause stackoverflow does not let me to submit the post without it

.animate{
        animation-name: bg_kf;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-delay: 0s;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-direction: normal;

```
    -webkit-animation-name: bg_kf;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;

    -moz-animation-name: bg_kf;
    -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;

    -o-animation-name: bg_kf;
    -o-animation-duration: 5s;
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-animation-delay: 0s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes bg_kf {
    from {background-color:#FFFFFF}
    to {background-color:red}
}

@-moz-keyframes bg_kf {
    from {background-color:#FFFFFF}
    to {background-color:red}
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg_kf {
    from {background-color:#FFFFFF}
    to {background-color:rgba(255, 140, 74, 0.16)}
}

@-o-keyframes bg_kf {
    from {background-color:#FFFFFF}
    to {background-color:rgba(255, 140, 74, 0.16)}
}
```

Any help appreciated
regards

Comment: For me the computed style is exactly what i have set in the styles. As you know the inline style takes precedent over styles set in a stylesheet. Might be something with your set up? Try a different browser?

Comment: @JamieHutber Click the div, then while it is animating, click the button that changes the background to black. You will notice nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the animation properties you have defined in `.animate` keep the background color red, regardless of what the actual inline style rule specifies. This is why toggling the inline style doesn't seem to have any effect.

If you were to remove the `.animate` class right after you apply the inline style, everything will once again be back to normal:

```
$("#sample").bind('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(){
    var computedBg = $(this).css('background-color');
    $(this).css('background-color', computedBg);
    $(this).removeClass('animate');
});
```

Here is a demonstration (try clicking the button after the animation has completed): http://jsfiddle.net/vcfDj/

Comment: you are right. But shouldn't the inline style take precedence instead of the class name?

Comment: @Thomas It does. If you add a `background-color` property to the class and a different `background-color` property inline, the inline property will be the one that "wins". Unfortunately we are looking at two entirely different CSS properties (animate vs background-color). Think of it this way: if I were to set a `height:100px` property inline, then apply a class that sets `display:none`, the computed height will still be 0 pixels, regardless of the fact that the active CSS for `height` is 100px.

Answer (score 0):

You've set animation-fill-mode "forwards".  The effect of that is to hold the animated CSS properties at the values they were when the animation ended (regardless of other style settings).  Setting it to "none" will fix your problem!